Unusual jumping/pausing/stalling of sustained throughput with LUKS and unexpected workaround
I have issue where encrypted volumes on spinning disks have strange behavior with sustained sequential operation (for example write of many-TB to freshly formatted EXT4 file system). There is significantly throughput deviation above the sustained throughput of the underlying device and then bellow, this repeats constantly during the whole transfer.
The combination of LVM + LUKS (as opposite just LUKS) causes this behavior be even worse and in this situation the throughput goes way above the sustained throughput of the disk and (2-3x) then down to 0. Constantly repeating.
I found the CloudFlare article where they talk about queuing of I/O with combination of SSD and dm-crypt. As I understand the work queues of dm-crypt cause performance degradation with SSDs, since the work queue have the job of making sure the asynchronous encryption/description doesn't change the resulting order of the I/O and this doesn't matter with SSD since SSD doesn't care what is the order of I/O and the work queues just add extra overhead for nothing. Yet with spinning disk the changed order could potentially convert sequential I/O into semi-random and that's bad for spinning disk since more seeking is for sure not good for performance (or the disk).
I tried this workaround anyway with the two above cases:
cryptsetup --perf-no_read_workqueue --perf-no_write_workqueue --persistent refresh <NAME>
This workaround cured the constantly jumping throughput and the sustained sequential performance even increased, with spinning disks...
I did more controlled many-TB write to EXT4 -> LUKS -> HDD and the result was that enabled work queues caused jumping throughput and disabling the work queues causes increase of sequential throughput by ~10% and the throughput is constant and it's the expected maximum for the given disk. Basically disabling those work queues make the disk behave as it would without dm-crypt/LUKS.
Since this should have the opposite effect - how this can even work? Random I/O (= more seeking) increases sequential performance on spinning disk? This is reproducible with two different systems (Ubuntu, Debian), with different LUKS or LUKS@LVM configuration and different spinning disks.
The disabling of work queues for spinning disks seem to work very well, too well in fact, but it shouldn't work at all! What I'm missing? Is there more appropriate cure of the jumping throughput (without disabling work queues of dm-crypt)?
